# To find the sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

It is a part of log function.
**please help me to find the sum of this infinite series
$$1+e^{2x}+e^{6x}+e^{12x}+e^{20x}+\ldots$$
or
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{n(n-1) x}$$**

I got this problem while deriving specific heat of solids with an-harmonic quantum state of a particle. In simpler case the series will be  $$1+e^{x}+e^{2x}+e^{3x}+e^{4x}+\ldots$$ Which can be summed by geometric progression formula.  $$({1-e^{x}})^{-1}$$
Here in this problem I tried all the special series that I know to sum the series. So, I need few directions to tackle the problem.

Comment: I doubt that there exists a closed form (for Claude Leibovici : without using special functions, I mean...).

Comment: Similar to an earlier question [Sum of a Series with steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4801800/89922)?

Comment: More than "similar": identical and by the same author! Arun, [reposting is forbidden here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6714/can-i-ask-the-same-question-twice).

Comment: Sir, can you please address the problem the question? So, that i can improve my posts.

Answer (score 1):

Your series converges (for $\text{Re}(x) < 0$) to $$\frac{\vartheta_2(0, e^x)}{2 e^{x/4}}$$
(in Abramowitz and Stegun's notation, also used by Maple), where $\vartheta_2$ is a Jacobi Theta function.